# Perl one-liner to empty directory explanation

Tags: perl

[This article](http://www.slashroot.in/which-is-the-fastest-method-to-delete-files-in-linux) pointed out one way to empty an directory with huge files with `perl`:

```
perl -e 'for(<*>){((stat)[9]<(unlink))}'
```

It made me confusing since when it called `stat` and compare with return value of `unlink` for every files.

I made a test without calling `stat` and the one-liner was faster. What's the purpose of calling `stat` here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stat is useless, it's probably a cargo cult attempt at performance optimization.

You can run it through [B::Deparse](http://metacpan.org/pod/B::Deparse) to see it's not doing anything funny.

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -e 'for(<*>){((stat)[9]<(unlink))}'
use File::Glob ();
foreach $_ (<*>) {
    (stat $_)[9] < unlink($_);
}
-e syntax OK
```

`(stat)[9]` is the file modification time in seconds since 1970, usually a large number.  `unlink` returns the number of files deleted, in this case its always going to be 0 or 1.  Nothing is checking that comparison anyway (add a -w and Perl will warn you about that).

This will do the same thing and faster.

```
perl -e 'unlink for <*>'
```

I have two guesses.  First is the author meant to write `(stat)[9] && unlink` which would check whether the file exists before unlinking it.  [Apparently there's some voodoo about this sometimes being faster](http://unix.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.unix.solaris/2008-03/msg01035.html).  This would be incorrect because `(stat)[9]` can return 0 even if the file exists.  Instead you'd want `-e && unlink`.  It's silly since you've just read the list of files in the directory.  It's also non-atomic.  It's also likely slower no matter how the kernel or filesystem behaves because the -e represents dozens of extra lines of C code.

My other guess is also optimization voodoo.  [I found this comment](http://blog.liw.fi/posts/rm-is-too-slow/#comment-9dc55dd2ade91f204d97e555d177c1d0) about doing a stat in a child process so the inode is already in the filesystem cache.  That's not what the Perl code is doing, but it might be some cargo culting.

Comment: That's also my first thinking, just want a confirmation from community. Thanks for making it more clearly.

Comment: Beat me to it. I also thought the `stat` redundant, but have been caught out before on obscure usages of perl functions.

Comment: Might be useful to include how to deparse the script and 'clarify' what it's doing.

Comment: @Sobrique Done.  And yeah, usually these things are taking advantage of some bizarre side effect, but I can't find one.

Comment: Re "This would be incorrect because `(stat)[9]` can return 0 even if the file exists", though it's not likely to return 0 for a file you can remove.

Comment: @ikegami How does that work?  There's lots of reasons (mostly mistakes) the mtime of a regular file might be set to 0.